# Setting spinner popup background color

Tags: android, android-spinner

I can set the background of the popup menu of a spinner using:

```
<Spinner
   android:popupBackground="@color/darkThemeBackgroundColor"/>
```

But how do I set the background text color of it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is more simpler, you only need add this code to styles.xml

```
<style name="spinnerTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    
    <!-- this is for api 19 text color -->
    <item name="android:color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And this is how use in your layout file

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:entries="@array/aves"
    android:theme="@style/spinnerTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

That is the result:

[image: This is the result]

I hope this solution helps you, greetings.

Comment: This does NOT change the background of the popup menu https://i.imgur.com/UHThmbo.png

Comment: Please see if the new answer help you.

Comment: This doesn't work on API 19 unfortunately. Do you have another solution? @Martin Bove

Comment: I'm going to check that, what problem do you see in API 19 @DIRTYDAVE

Comment: The textColor doesn't set on API 19. https://i.imgur.com/SkEUHiG.png I want it to be white, but it stays black. The background is supposed to be black, so thats why I need the text to be white, I just change it so red, just to demonstrate. If the text is black on api 19 it will be difficult to see

Comment: I tried in api 19 and found the solution, we need to use the color attribute for api 19. I have updated the response code.

Comment: It's still not working for me :/ https://pastebin.com/faBHFzhu I'm testing on a API 19 -Samsung Galaxy Note 3 real device. Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: I do not have that device to test unfortunately, I tested it in an emulator with api19.

you can try in an emulator to rule out that it is a problem only with the samsung

Comment: I had a similar problem with the miui layer of the xiaomi where today I cannot set a wallpaper for the lock screen.